# Why is my python code for youtube api for youtube data analysis giving me error in phycharm but not in jupyter notebook?

Tags: pycharm, youtube-data-api

Problem depicted in the following pictures.
[Error Message in pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37d3S.png)
[Code executed in pycharm. Here the playlist_id has been extracted through youtube api.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH7tE.png)
[Code executed in jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8b4R.png)

The only difference between the playlist_id is that in jupyter notebook, it is in string format. However, in pycharm its data type is pandas.core.series.Series as it is one of the data from a column of a dataframe. However, I have even converted it into string also before passing it into the get_video_ids function. But still the error persists.

Hope to get the answers soon for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass `Series` to this function.

Check the exception. You can see `...playlistId=2++++UUcY...`, where `...playlistId=UUcY...` is expected. It clearly got confused by the `Series` string representation, which includes index `2` with four spaces.